# how to install mariasql with nodejs 4.x on ubuntu 14?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to set server with node.js and mariaDB on Ubuntu at EC2 of AWS.

here is the versions what I installed..

```
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
MariaDB 10.1.14
NodeJS 4.4.7
```

now I want to connect with node.js and mariaDB, so I tried to install mariasql
with this command..

```
$sudo npm install mariasql
```

but this errors occurred..

```
========================================================================
gyp ERR! build error  
gyp ERR! stack Error: not found: make 
gyp ERR! stack     at getNotFoundError (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:14:12) 
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:69:19) 
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:81:29) 
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:90:16 
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/index.js:44:5 
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/node_modules/isexe/access.js:8:5 gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15) 
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-74-generic 
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" 
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/node_modules/mariasql 
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7 
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1 
gyp ERR! not ok  

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-74-generic 
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mariasql" 
npm ERR! node v4.4.7 
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! mariasql@0.2.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild` 
npm ERR! Exit status 1 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR! Failed at the mariasql@0.2.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'. 
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mariasql package, 
npm ERR! not with npm itself. 
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: 
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with: npm ERR!     npm bugs mariasql 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via: 
npm ERR!  
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mariasql 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: 
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/npm-debug.log

========================================================================
```

already installed node-gyp.
I tried old version of node, it was 0.10.x but it didn't work as well.
what did I wrong with it?

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo to install npm packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have `build-essential` installed?

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Also, did you install `node-gyp` as global?

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp
```

This is important, please see there is `-g` flag